# Using session storage to save values in a form

Tags: javascript, html

Currently trying to use the following script to save the billing information i've included below on a page refresh. Hoping that this would clear up further errors i'm having down the line with redirecting users to paypal.

```
<script>
    // Run on page load
    window.onload = function() {

        // If sessionStorage is storing default values (ex. name), exit the function and do not restore data
        if (sessionStorage.getItem('billing_firstname') == "billing_firstname") {
            return;
        }

        // If values are not blank, restore them to the fields
        var billing_firstname = sessionStorage.getItem('billing_firstname');
        if (billing_firstname !== null) $('#billing_firstname').val(billing_firstname);

        var billing_state= sessionStorage.getItem('billing_state');
        if (billing_state !== null) $('#billing_state').val(billing_state);

        var billing_country= sessionStorage.getItem('billing_country');
        if (billing_country!== null) $('#billing_country').val(billing_country);


    }

    // Before refreshing the page, save the form data to sessionStorage
    window.onbeforeunload = function() {
        sessionStorage.setItem("billing_firstname", $('#billing_firstname').val());
        sessionStorage.setItem("billing_state", $('#billing_state').val());
        sessionStorage.setItem("billing_country", $('#billing_country').val());

    }
</script>
```

To save the following form (not added all the form labels to the script yet)

```
<div id="billing_info" class="pad10 boxShadow" style="display:block"> 
          <!--START: SAVE_ADDRESSES-->
          <div class="chkField">
            <label for="save_address">[checkout3_PreviousAddresses]</label>
            <select type="dropdown" name="save_address" onchange="javascript:filladdress_form(this,'billing','billing');check_address('billing');" tabindex="1" class="txtBoxStyle">

              [address_billing_list]

            </select>
            <div class="clear"></div>
          </div>
          <!--END: SAVE_ADDRESSES-->
          <div class="chkField">
            <label for="billing_firstname">[CustomerInfo_firstname]</label>
            <input name="billing_firstname" onchange="clearContent(this);" type="text" id="billing_firstname" value="[billing_firstname]" size="15" tabindex="2" class="txtBoxStyle" />
            <!--START: req_billing_firstname--> 
            <img src="assets/templates/common/images/error2.gif" width="12" height="12" alt="" /> 
            <!--END: req_billing_firstname-->
            <div class="clear"></div>
          </div>
          <div class="chkField">
            <label for="billing_lastname">[CustomerInfo_lastname]</label>
            <input name="billing_lastname" type="text" onchange="clearContent(this);" id="billing_lastname" value="[billing_lastname]" size="15" tabindex="3" class="txtBoxStyle" />
            <!--START: req_billing_lastname--> 
            <img src="assets/templates/common/images/error2.gif" width="12" height="12" alt="" /> 
            <!--END: req_billing_lastname-->
            <div class="clear"></div>
          </div>






          <div class="chkField">
            <label for="billing_company">[CustomerInfo_company]</label>
            <input name="billing_company" type="text" onchange="clearContent(this);" id="billing_company" value="[billing_company]" size="25" tabindex="4" class="txtBoxStyle" />
            <div class="clear"></div>
          </div>

<div class="chkField">
            <label for="billing_state">[CustomerInfo_state]</label>
            <select id="billing_state" onchange="this.form.billing_zip.value='';check_address('billing');" name="billing_state" tabindex="9" class="txtBoxStyle">
            </select>
            <!--START: req_billing_state--> 
            <img src="assets/templates/common/images/error2.gif" width="12" height="12" alt="" /> 
            <!--END: req_billing_state-->
            <div class="clear"></div>
          </div>



<div class="chkField">
            <label for="billing_country">[CustomerInfo_country]</label>
            <select name="billing_country" onchange="check_address('billing');" tabindex="8" class="txtBoxStyle" id="billing_country">
            </select>
            <!--START: req_billing_country--> 
            <img src="assets/templates/common/images/error2.gif" width="12" height="12" alt="" /> 
            <!--END: req_billing_country-->
            <div class="clear"></div>
          </div>


          <div class="chkField">
            <label for="billing_address">[CustomerInfo_address]</label>
            <input name="billing_address" type="text" onchange="clearContent(this);[po_box_disabled_billing]" id="billing_address" value="[billing_address]" size="25" tabindex="5" class="txtBoxStyle" />
            <!--START: req_billing_address--> 
            <img src="assets/templates/common/images/error2.gif" width="12" height="12" alt="" /> 
            <!--END: req_billing_address-->
            <div class="clear"></div>
          </div>
          <div class="chkField">
            <label for="billing_address2">[CustomerInfo_address2]</label>
            <input name="billing_address2" type="text" onchange="clearContent(this);" id="billing_address2" value="[billing_address2]" size="25" tabindex="6" class="txtBoxStyle" />
            <div class="clear"></div>
          </div>
          <div class="chkField">
            <label for="billing_city">[CustomerInfo_city]</label>
            <input name="billing_city" type="text" onchange="clearContent(this);" id="billing_city" value="[billing_city]" size="25" tabindex="7" class="txtBoxStyle" />
            <!--START: req_billing_city--> 
            <img src="assets/templates/common/images/error2.gif" width="12" height="12" alt="" /> 
            <!--END: req_billing_city-->
            <div class="clear"></div>
          </div>


          <div class="chkField">
            <label for="billing_zip">[CustomerInfo_zip]</label>
            <input name="billing_zip" maxlength="15" type="text" id="billing_zip" value="[billing_zip]" size="10" tabindex="10" class="txtBoxStyle" onchange="clearContent(this);check_address('billing');" />
            <!--START: req_billing_zip--> 
            <img src="assets/templates/common/images/error2.gif" width="12" height="12" alt="" /> 
            <!--END: req_billing_zip-->
            <div class="clear"></div>
          </div>

                  <div class="chkField">
            <label for="billing_phone">[CustomerInfo_phone]</label>
            <input name="billing_phone" type="text" onchange="clearContent(this);" id="billing_phone" value="[billing_phone]" size="25" tabindex="5" class="txtBoxStyle" />
            <!--START: req_billing_phone--> 
            <img src="assets/templates/common/images/error2.gif" width="12" height="12" alt="" /> 
            <!--END: req_billing_phone-->
            <div class="clear"></div>
          </div>

        <div class="clear"></div>
```

I'm getting the following error.

```
Uncaught TypeError: $ is not a function
    at window.onbeforeunload
```

new error

```
Uncaught TypeError: $ is not a function
    at checkout_one.asp:1903
    at dispatch (jquery.min.js:2)
    at y.handle (jquery.min.js:2)
```

After adding

```
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

I have not called the script from anywhere in my code as of yet.

Comment: do u have jquery in your project ??

Comment: No i do not. Is that the issue?

Comment: please include that and tell me if error persist

Comment: Fraid not changed the error

Comment: "I have not called the script from anywhere in my code as of yet." yes you have...`$('#billing_firstname')` is the first instance of it in the sample above. It runs when the page loads. Is this the line which is referred to as 1903 in the new error message? If not, which line is it? And where did you place your jquery script tag? Inside the `<head>` of the page is usually the best place

Answer (score 0):

```
<script>    

$( window ).load(function() {

    if (sessionStorage.getItem('billing_firstname') == "billing_firstname") 
    {
        return;
    }

    // If values are not blank, restore them to the fields
    var billing_firstname = sessionStorage.getItem('billing_firstname');
    if (billing_firstname !== null) $('#billing_firstname').val(billing_firstname);

    var billing_state= sessionStorage.getItem('billing_state');
    if (billing_state !== null) $('#billing_state').val(billing_state);

    var billing_country= sessionStorage.getItem('billing_country');
    if (billing_country!== null) $('#billing_country').val(billing_country);


}
});


 $( window ).unload(function() {

    sessionStorage.setItem("billing_firstname", 
    $('#billing_firstname').val());
    sessionStorage.setItem("billing_state", $('#billing_state').val());
    sessionStorage.setItem("billing_country", $('#billing_country').val());
});

</script>
```

and include jquery before any script library included or before this code ... first script should be jquery :

```
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

and please post error after this since u r using jquery $(" ") without jquery i think you are mixing js and jquery in bad way . please check this once .